# Using Python to view Outlook Emails live / for the next 1 hour or so

Tags: python, datetime, time, outlook

I am doing a personal project to properly understand python. Recently started coding.

The below code gets me the last email from a particular folder and then it applies regular expressions to the body and It fill some details in a webform.

The part am stuck at is to get live emails or emails for the next hours. Is there a way to keep the program running so it fetches live emails for the next few hours one after the other rather than last,

```
import win32com.client
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime,timedelta 
import time


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders['keelanur.nishanth@nxp.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['NXDI Maintenace LSF']
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.Body


#Regular expression code
...

#Selenium web driver code for form filling.
```

Would like to know if there is any way to keep the code running so it gets one email after another for the next few hours.

I tried to make changes to code for the past few hours and days which I found on stackover flow but was unable to. Could someone please help me.
Have a nice day :)

Comment: You could wrap it all in a while loop that keeps the program looping and add time.sleep at the end of the loop with whatever interval you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about that in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Outlook evaluates date-time values according to the time format, short date format, and long date format settings in the Regional and Language Options applet in the Windows Control Panel. In particular, Outlook evaluates time according to that specified time format without seconds. If you specify seconds in the date-time comparison string, the filter will not operate as expected.

Although dates and times are typically stored with a date format, filters using the Jet and DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax require that the date-time value to be converted to a string representation. In Jet syntax, the date-time comparison string should be enclosed in either double quotes or single quotes. In DASL syntax, the date-time comparison string should be enclosed in single quotes.

To make sure that the date-time comparison string is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the Visual Basic for Applications Format function (or its equivalent in your programming language).

For example, most probably you will be interested in the

```
'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
& " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
& AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
& " < '" & datEndUTC & "'"
```

Most probably you will be interested in the [MailItem.ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) property value to sort items (it returns a date indicating the date and time at which the item was received).

The [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) article shows how to construct a search criteria in depth.

> Would like to know if there is any way to keep the code running so it gets one email after another for the next few hours.

You can run extract emails for each hour in the outer loop. In the inner loop you can iterate over the email found for a particular hour. Otherwise, you may consider running a timer. In the tick event you may process each hour, i.e. emails for a particular hour.